# Pass value from input component to button component in Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-components

I'm trying to figure how to pass value from one Angular component to another `my-input.component` and `my-button.component`:

I'm trying to receive from `my-input.component.ts` and display `@Input('name')` with button `(click)="displayReceivedValue()"` from `my-button.component.html` in `my-button.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyInput } from '../../interfaces/my-input';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-button',
  templateUrl: './my-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-button.component.scss'],
})
export class MyButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('name')
  public input!: MyInput;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  async displayReceivedValue() {
    console.log('Received value: ', this.input);
  }
}
```

which is `<app-my-button name=""></app-my-button>` component in `Login page` `login.component.html` from `my-input.component.ts` with `this.myValue` from `[(ngModel)]="myValue"` in `input` of `my-input.component.html`, but I'm not sure, how to pass it to `name=""`:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-input',
  templateUrl: './my-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-input.component.scss'],
})
export class MyInputComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public myValue: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Also I've tried use `@Output()` with   `<app-my-button (inputValue)="acceptData($event)"></app-my-button>` component in `Login page` from  `my-input.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-my-input',
      templateUrl: './my-input.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./my-input.component.scss'],
    })
    export class MyInputComponent implements OnInit {
      @Output() inputValue= new EventEmitter<string>();
        
      public myValue: any;

      constructor() {}
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
           this.inputValue.emit(this.inputValue);
      }
    }
```

in `my-button.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-button',
  templateUrl: './my-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-button.component.scss'],
})
export class MyButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  acceptData(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

I got nothing if I add `(inputValue)="acceptData($event)` to `my-button.component.html`, or if I add `(inputValue)="acceptData($event)` to `login.component.html` I got error:

> TS2339: Property 'acceptData' does not exist on type
> 'LoginComponent'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1: Using ControlValueAccessor

Try to make it simple; Lets say you have below in your app component

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-my-input [(ngModel)]='myValue'></app-my-input>
<app-my-button [name]='myValue'></app-my-button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```typescript
 myValue = 'MyValue'
```

Basically we are binding to the same value in the `app.component.ts`. So the value will be updated to the button `name` property when it changes.

Now if you try to run above you will receive an error

> No value accessor for control with the name `app-my-input`

That is because we are binding to the `ngModel` that requires to implement `ControlValueAccessor`. So we implement this like below

**my-input.component.ts**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-input',
  templateUrl: './my-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-input.component.css'],
    providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyInputComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    ]
})
export class MyInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  
  myValue = '';
  constructor() { }
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      this.myValue = value;
    }
  }
  onChanges: ($value: any) => void;
  onTouched: () => void;

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChanges = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

**my-input.component.ts**

```html
<input [(ngModel)]='myValue' (ngModelChange)='onChanges(myValue)'>
```

Now our `app-my-input` works just like a normal input and we can bind to the `[(ngModel)]` directive

So now in our `app-my-button` we can receive this using `@Input` decorator

**app-my-button.ts**

```typescript
  @Input() name = "";
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  displayReceivedValue() {
    console.log("Received value: ", this.name);
  }
```

**app-my-button.html**

```html
<button (click)='displayReceivedValue()'>My button</button>
```

Now if you click on the button you will see a log in the console with the value of the input

[**Demo Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ohtcpb)

### Option 2: Using `@Output` and `@input` decorators

To use `@input` and `@Output` you would simply define you are input with something like

```typescript
export class MyInputComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @Input() input = '';
  @Output() output: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter()
  myValue = '';
  constructor() { }
  onChanges = ($event) => {
    this.output.emit($event)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myValue = this.input
  }
}
```

and in the html

```html
<input [(ngModel)]='myValue' (ngModelChange)='onChanges(myValue)'>
```

Now we bind to `(ngModelChange)`. When the value changes, we emit the value using the `output` property defined as an `EventEmitter<string>`

We can then receive this with

```html
<app-my-input [input]='myValue' (output)="myValue = $event"></app-my-input>
```

[See this Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j51gln)

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the late reply. So I've to use 'ngModel' and 'name' in 'app-my-input' and 'app-my-button' components on 'app.component.html' from  '[(ngModel)]="myValue" (ngModelChange)="onChanges(myValue)"' in 'my-input.component.html', provided code gives the required result and I will be marked as an answer, but as I am new with Angular, I'm still trying to figure out, how to use 'output' and 'Input' in the same task. I'm looking into Angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs, but looks like I'm missing something because the value is always undefined

Comment: See my approach above in the updated solution